# join thread after start_new_thread

Tags: python, multithreading, join

below function exits after 3 seconds when i run it separately, but when i call it in a thread it never exits. kindly suggest what is wrong in this code.

```
def display(val1, val2):

    root =  Tk()
    clock = Label(root, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='white')
    clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
    def tick():
        time1 = val1 +'\n' + val2
        clock.config(text=time1)
    tick()
    root.after(3000,root.quit)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am calling above function in my program as

```
thread.start_new_thread(display,(val1,val2))
```

thread starts appropriately and main program continues but the display function does not exit after 3 seconds, pls suggest how to join this thread or destroy it without affecting main program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

In my testing, I think your actual problem is with tkinter. You want `Tk.destroy()` not `Tk.quit()`

```
from tkinter import * # < Python3.x you will need Tkinter not tkinter.
from threading import Thread

def display(val1, val2):
    root =  Tk()
    clock = Label(root, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='white')
    clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
    def tick():
        time1 = val1 +'\n' + val2
        clock.config(text=time1)
    tick()
    root.after(3000, root.destroy)
    root.mainloop()

thread = Thread(target=display, args=("1", "2"))
thread.start()
```

This worked for me.

From before:

You should take a look at the higher-level [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module. It's a better choice.

To join the thread:

```
from threading import Thread
...
thread = Thread(target=display, args=(val1, val2))
thread.start()
...
thread.join()
```

An alternative to this is the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
process = Process(target=display, args=(val1, val2))
process.start()
...
process.join()
```

And unlike `threading` or `thread`, `multiprocessing` offers [`Process.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate).

Comment: hey sorry Process is not letting my main program continue but making it wait until this new Process finishes, pls help

Comment: @RAFIQ That is the expected behavior of `process.join()` - it blocks until `process` finishes. Do the stuff you want to do concurrently before that call.

Comment: @lvc can you brief how? infact start_new_thread is non-blocking but, can we join or terminate it without affecting the main program?

Comment: @RAFIQ `process.start()` is also non-blocking, and will start a concurrent process. Anything in the second `...` in Lattyware's code will run concurrently with `process`. `process.join()` says: "stop running concurrently, and wait for `process` to finish by itself before doing anything else". You can't join without blocking, since blocking is exactly what join *does*. `process.terminate()` ends `process` without waiting for it to finish what it's doing, and so should be non-blocking.

Comment: Non-blocking is exactly what i want, but can we somehow terminate the new thread? or atleast i want display to run only for 3 seconds.

Comment: @RAFIQ In that case, it's really an issue with the thread you are running. Something must be happening that is causing your thread not to quit as expected. You don't want to be managing when the thread ends from your main thread.

Comment: @Lattyware i am actually importing this function into the program, does this in anyway influence it not to quit, just wild guess

Comment: @RAFIQ See my edit, I believe you need to use ``Tk.destroy()`` not ``Tk.quit()``.

Comment: @Lattyware That works, so dumb me, so does that mean start_new_thread, Thread or process(without join()) will silently quit after the function execution and we need not bother about terminating them?

Comment: @RAFIQ Yes, threads end when the code runs out - simple as that. ``join()`` is used to make one thread wait for another to finish before doing something, and ``terminate()`` to kill a thread while it's still doing things. Neither should be necessary in most cases, just fire and forget.